Forall $x \in \mathbb{Z}_p \setminus\{0\}$ can be written as $x= p^n u$ with $n \in \mathbb{N} \cup \{0\}$, $u \in \Bbb{Z}_p\setminus p \Bbb{Z}_p$
I want to understand the proof of the following statement:
Let $\mathbb{Z}_p$ denote the $p$-adic integers.
Every element $x \in \mathbb{Z}_p \setminus\{0\}$ can be written as $x= p^n u$ with $n \in \mathbb{N} \cup \{0\}$, $u \in \mathbb{Z}_p\setminus p \mathbb{Z}_p$.
Proof:
Let $x \in \mathbb{Z}_p \setminus\{0\}$. Since $\displaystyle \bigcap_{n \in \mathbb{N} \cup \{0\}} p^n \mathbb{Z}_p=0$ there exists a unique $n \in \mathbb{N}_0$ with $x \in p^{n} \mathbb{Z}_{p} \setminus p^{n+1}\mathbb{Z}_{p}$. $(*)$ Thus we can write $x=p^n u$, where $u \in \mathbb{Z}_p \setminus p \mathbb{Z}_p$.
I understand the proof up to $(*)$. I do not see why we can write $x$ as $p^n u$.

First of all, you have to see what is the meaning of $x \in p^n \mathbb{Z}_p \setminus p^{n+1}\mathbb{Z}_p$. This means that $x$ is one of the elements of $\Bbb{Z}_{p}$, which has a valuation $n$. This you can prove easily because $x \in p^n \mathbb{Z}_p$, means $ x = p^{n}u$, for some $u \in \Bbb{Z}_{p}$. Now $v_{p}(u) = 0$, because if it is greater than zero, then it will cause that $v_{p}(x) \geq n+1$, but that is not possible because $x \in p^n \mathbb{Z}_p \setminus p^{n+1}\mathbb{Z}_p$. And it is easy to see that $v_{p}(u) = 0 \iff u \in \mathbb{Z}_{p} \setminus p\Bbb{Z}_{p}$.
Because, if we look little closely the set $p^{n}\Bbb{Z}_{p} \setminus p^{n+1}\Bbb{Z}_{p} = \{x \in \Bbb{Z}_{p}: p^{n} \mid  x ~\text{but}~ p^{n+1} \nmid x\} = \{x \in \Bbb{Z}_{p} : v_{p}(x) = n\}~ \forall ~ n \in \Bbb{N} \cup \{0\}$,  as $v_{p}(x) = \max\{n: p^{n} \mid x\} = \{x: p^{n} \mid x ~\text{but}~ p^{n+1} \nmid x\}$. It is also clear that for $n = 0$, the above set will be $\Bbb{Z}_{p} \setminus p\Bbb{Z}_{p} = \{x \in \Bbb{Z}_{p} : v_{p}(x) = 0\}$. So we can write generally $v_{p}(x) = n \iff x \in p^{n}\Bbb{Z}_{p} \setminus p^{n+1}\Bbb{Z}_{p}$.
There is also an alternative approach you can see if you want:
We know that $v_{p}(\mathbb{Z}_{p} \setminus \{0\}) = \mathbb{N} \cup \{0\}$. So for any $x \in \mathbb{Z}_{p} \setminus \{0\}$ we can write $v_{p}(x) = n$, for some $n \in \Bbb{N} \cup \{0\}$. So we can write that
$$v_{p}(x) = nv_{p}(p) = v_{p}(p^{n}) ~ \text{(As}~ v_{p}~ \text{is additive})
\\ \implies v_{p}(x/p^{n}) = 0$$
which implies $x/p^{n}$ is a unit element, so we can assume that $x/p^{n} = u$, for some unit element. So $x = p^{n}u$, for some $n \in \Bbb{N}\cup \{0\}$ and $u \in \Bbb{Z}_{p}\setminus p\Bbb{Z}_{p}$.

Here's a version of the proof that doesn't mention the valuation $v_p$ (and probably includes more details than you need). Since $x\in p^n\mathbb Z_p\setminus p^{n+1}\mathbb Z_p$, we  have in particular that $x\in p^n\mathbb Z_p$, which means that $x=p^nu$ for some $u\in\mathbb Z_p$. To get the desired conclusion, $u\in\mathbb Z_p\setminus p\mathbb Z_p$, we still need to show that $u\notin p\mathbb Z_p$. Well, suppose, toward a contradiction, that $u\in p\mathbb Z_p$, so $u=pv$ for some $v\in\mathbb Z_p$. But then $x=p^nu=p^{n+1}v\in p^{n+1}\mathbb Z_p$, contradicting the fact that $x\in p^n\mathbb Z_p\setminus p^{n+1}\mathbb Z_p$.
